# İonic 3 with Angular-map (agm) Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function

Tags: angular, ionic3, ionic-native, angular-google-maps

I have ionic 3 project using angular google map, after some update I have problems in map pages, it says

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
>       at new FitBoundsService

How can fix this problem?

Ny environment.

Ionic:

```
ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.9.0 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.5
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.1
```

Cordova:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
Cordova Platforms     : android 7.1.4, ios 4.5.5
Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.4.1, (and 13 other plugins)
```

System:

```
ios-deploy : 1.9.2
NodeJS     : v8.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
npm        : 6.9.0
OS         : macOS Mojave
Xcode      : Xcode 10.2.1 Build version 10E1001
```

1. I have downgraded the agm/core to 1.0.0-beta2 and 3
2. I have installed rxjs 6 , but it give me more error because Im using angular 5.

this is mu package.json

```
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ionic-app-scripts serve",
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "@angular/animations": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/common": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/core": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/forms": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/http": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.2.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.2.11",
    "@ionic-native/camera": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "~4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/device": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/geolocation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/in-app-browser": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/keyboard": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/launch-navigator": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/photo-viewer": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/screen-orientation": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/social-sharing": "^4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "~4.20.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "~4.20.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^9.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "@servicestack/client": "^1.0.15",
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.16",
    "@types/node": "^11.9.4",
    "com-sarriaroman-photoviewer": "^1.2.2",
    "cordova-android": "7.1.4",
    "cordova-ios": "4.5.5",
    "cordova-plugin-actionsheet": "^2.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-camera": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard": "git+https://github.com/mrchandoo/cordova-plugin-decimal-keyboard.git",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-dialogs": "^2.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^4.2.1",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation": "^4.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-googleplus": "^7.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser": "^3.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.4.1",
    "cordova-plugin-screen-orientation": "^3.0.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing": "^5.4.4",
    "es6-promise-plugin": "^4.2.2",
    "ionic-angular": "^3.9.2",
    "ionic3-star-rating": "^1.1.5",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "is": "3.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng2-simple-global": "^1.2.5",
    "ngx-moment": "^3.3.0",
    "q": "^1.5.1",
    "rxjs": "5.5.11",
    "socket.io-client": "^2.2.0",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.launchnavigator": "^5.0.4",
    "zone.js": "0.8.29"
```

Comment: I am using the same beta3. try to use "rxjs": "^5.5.2", instead of 5.5.11

Comment: thanks Indraraj ,I have set to rxjs 5.5.2 but still the same problem, can you please check your package json and compare it with mine, or ca you please paste yor json here?